# Get Declared Fields in c++ like in Java

Tags: c++

is there a way to get all fields in c++ Like in Java:
`this.getClass().getDeclaredFields()`

I would appreciate an answer

Comment: Not sure what java  getDeclaredFields() does but c++ doesn't have reflection yet so it's not possible yet. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68761022/reflection-ts-in-c23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68761022/reflection-ts-in-c23)

Comment: No this would require reflection information which C++ doesn't have.

Comment: You can not overflow dot operator in C++. C++ is not Java.